# Arrange downloaded data into more useful way in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

We currently have a fixed report data that we can only manipulate after download and to simplify, it looks like this:

**raw report data extracted to google sheets**

```
    a           b                                   c
1   Start Date  Time Adhering to Schedule (Hours)   Time Not Adhering to Schedule (Hours)
2   Employee: A                                     Supervisor: X
3   5/4/2022    7.65                                1.35
4   5/5/2022    8.12                                0.88
5   5/6/2022    6.95                                2.05
6   5/9/2022    8.7                                 0.3
7   5/10/2022   7.45                                1.55
8   5/11/2022   8.63                                0.37
9   5/12/2022   8.08                                0.92
10  5/13/2022   6.13                                0.13
11  Totals:     61.71                               7.55
12  Employee: B                                     Supervisor: X
13  5/1/2022    3.8                                 0.27
14  5/2/2022    6.72                                2.28
15  5/3/2022    6.1                                 2.9
16  5/4/2022    8.43                                0.57
17  5/5/2022    5.85                                0.53
18  5/10/2022   6.13                                2.87
19  5/11/2022   0                                   1.5
20  5/12/2022   2                                   1.5
21  5/13/2022   1.75                                1.75
22  Totals:     40.78                               14.17
```

I would like some help in constructing a new sheet via formulas so that it rearranges the raw data as follows:

**desired output**

```
    a           b           c           d                                   e   
1   EMPLOYEE    SUPERVISOR  Start Date  Time Adhering to Schedule (Hours)   Time Not Adhering to Schedule (Hours)
2   A           X           04/05/22    7.65                                1.35
3   A           X           05/05/22    8.12                                0.88
4   A           X           06/05/22    6.95                                2.05
5   A           X           09/05/22    8.70                                0.30
6   A           X           10/05/22    7.45                                1.55
7   A           X           11/05/22    8.63                                0.37
8   A           X           12/05/22    8.08                                0.92
9   A           X           13/05/22    6.13                                0.13
10  B           X           01/05/22    3.80                                0.27
11  B           X           02/05/22    6.72                                2.28
12  B           X           03/05/22    6.10                                2.90
13  B           X           04/05/22    8.43                                0.57
14  B           X           05/05/22    5.85                                0.53
15  B           X           10/05/22    6.13                                2.87
16  B           X           11/05/22    0.00                                1.50
17  B           X           12/05/22    2.00                                1.50
18  B           X           13/05/22    1.75                                1.75
```

It probably needs some combination of QUERY() ARRAYFORMULA(), TRANSPOSE() and/or INDEX() or something.. but i can't quite figure it out. I need some help with to get started in the right track. the dates and data between employees are dynamic so the formula in the desired result needs to adjust to that as well.

thanks!

edit: adding a sample trix for reference :) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m_FCGcnXvnEiMZ8X4K1eEsMljORWV4V1Yq_81vFnx4Y/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Gobal solution

in E1

```
={ArrayFormula(if(A1:A="Totals:",,{
substitute(lookup(row(A1:A),row(A1:A)/if(ISNUMBER(A1:A),0,1),A1:A),"Employee: ",""),
substitute(lookup(row(A1:A),row(A1:A)/if(ISNUMBER(A1:A),0,1),C1:C),"Supervisor: ","")
})),Arrayformula(if(ISNUMBER(A1:A),{A1:A,B1:B,C1:C},))}
```

[image]

### In 3 steps (3 arrayformulas),

try in H1

```
=arrayformula(if(left(A1:A,6)="Totals",,if(left(A1:A,8)="Employee",{B1:B,D1:D,E1:E,E1:E,E1:E},{E1:E,E1:E,A1:A,B1:B,C1:C})))
```

then, back in F1 to complete all rows with employee and supervisor

```
=ArrayFormula({lookup(row(H:H),row(H:H)/if(H:H<>"",1,0),H:H),lookup(row(I:I),row(I:I)/if(I:I<>"",1,0),I:I)})
```

finally, if you want to reduce the presentation, in M1

```
=query(F:L,"select F,G,J,K,L where J is not null",0)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the formulas! Will start from those you share. btw, i added a sample trix for reference (should have added this sooner).

Comment: I have added a solution with only one formule